# kohana kostache partial logic

Tags: php, kohana, partial, kohana-3.2, kostache

Started an project using kostache.

I have made some partials like banner,navigatons and footer in my class View_Layout with extends kostache_layout . Partials work fine on each page.

One problem. The navigation show always the same links. My goal is to show links that are appropriate to the user who is logged. How can I put logic in the partial of navigation? I know I can write functions in the View_Layout class but View_Layout must know the user role?

Hope somebody can help me.

Answer (score 0):

In mustache, partials inherit from the surrounding template's variable stack. You'd need to do this logic in your view class. If different pages need different links, do that in your specific view class.

Answer (score 0):

#### Option 1: evolve your views

The best option would be to expand the capabilities of your views. Actually in MVC-inspired patterns the views should be instances which handle UI logic and can choose from which (usually, more then one) templates to create the response. If that response even needs to be a HTML .. maybe a simple HTP header would be enough.

The default toolset in Kohana is geared towards very simple usecases, but it is possible to expand it.

My recommendation would be start using fully implemented views.

#### Option 2: use HMVC

Alternatively, you can utilize HMVC capabilities in Kohana. This would mean, that you have one or few "main controllers", which then create sub-requests. The responses from those requests is passed in/bound to the template, which said controller supervise.

In you particular case the menu would be governed by separate sub-controller.